# Migrating PostgreSQL DB from AWS to Alibaba Cloud

Tags: postgresql, migration, amazon-rds

I'm migrating **PostgreSQL RDS** instance from AWS located in Frankfurt to the RDS instance in Alibaba Cloud also located in Frankfurt.
I use **Data Transmission** tool from Alibaba Cloud. It connects both DB fine, there are *no errors on the connections*.
The only problem is with **versioning**:

[image: unsupported version]

I've tried downgrading the source DB, but it seems to be impossible. Does anybody have ideas how it could be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* downgrade postgresql database from the command line.

Simply extract the database with a

```
pg_dump --host=... --port=... --dbname=.... --user=.... >dump
```

command. Then you will have your database in the file `dump` in your local directory.

Then insert the dump into your new database with the command

```
psql --host=... --port=... --dbname=.... --user=.... <dump
```

It won't work at first. Typically, you will have syntax errors or similar. But get a good text editor, and edit it all out, until it won't be clean.

Comment: Yes! Thanks, managed to work with this solution.